# How do I get an RGBCurves value in an addon menu?

Tags: python, node-editor, interface, add-on

I'm sure you've all had enough of me by now, but I need to get this working, so I'm just going to power through.

Is there a way to get this:

[image]

into my addon menu?

Ideally it should be hidden by default, and activate with this bool:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials["Skin"]
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
curve = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["DarkCurve"]
BSDF = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
mainmix = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["MainMix"]

def dark_switch(self, context):
    for tex in bpy.data.materials:
        if (self.my_bool == True):
            #print ("Property Enabled")
            mat.node_tree.links.new(curve.outputs[0], BSDF.inputs[0])
            bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["DarkLight"].blend_type = 'LIGHTEN'
        else:
            #print ("Property Disabled")
            mat.node_tree.links.new(mainmix.outputs[0], BSDF.inputs[0])
            bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["DarkLight"].blend_type = 'DARKEN'
            
            
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Scene Properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyProperties(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(
        name="DarkSkin",
        description="Tick for Dark Skin",
        default = False,
        update = dark_switch
        )
```

Which I figured out yesterday, and works perfectly for what it currently does.

Comment: Please be more specific, what do you mean by "this"? Do you want to show the curve widget? Add a curve node in a shader?

Comment: The widget, I suppose. You know when you select a node in the editor it shows up on the side bar in that window? As in my example pic. I need that.
I also need the same for some colorramp nodes eventually, I'm hoping if I get one working I'll be able to figure out both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, after a lot of poking around in the API docs.

```
curve = bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["RGBCurve"]
layout.template_curve_mapping(curve, "mapping", type='COLOR')
```

It shows up perfectly, and updates live.

The only thing I don't have it doing is hiding until the tick box is activated.
I'd appreciate any advice on that.